# How to find the preimage of a set

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm trying to prove continuity of two different functions $f\colon A\to B$. I know that to find continuity, the inverse of all open subsets in $B$ must be open in $A$. I also know that to find the inverse of an open subset you have to find the preimage. I just don't know how to find the preimage. How do you find the preimage?

For example, if the set is the discrete topology of $\{1,2,3\}$, how would you find the preimage of $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, etc. The same for the indiscrete topology. How would you find the preimage of the null set and the whole set? Thank you!

Comment: Do you understand what "preimage of a set under a function" means? You need a set and a function.

Comment: A couple more comments: 1) the set is $\{1,2,3\}$ *with* discrete topology, not "the set **is** the discrete topology of" 2) preimages have *nothing* to do with topology, 3) we don't say "the inverse of all open sets", we say directly "the preimages of all open sets"

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:A\to B$ be a map and let $S$ be a subset of $B$, then the preimage of $S$ under $f$ is
$$f^{-1}(S)=\{a\,|\,f(a)\in S\}.$$
For example if $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{a,b,c\}$ and $f$ is map defined by $f(1)=f(2)=a$, $f(3)=b$, then 
$$f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset,\\
f^{-1}(\{a\})=\{1,2\},\ 
f^{-1}(\{b\})=\{3\},\ 
f^{-1}(\{c\})=\emptyset,\\
f^{-1}(\{a,b\})=\{1,2,3\},\ 
f^{-1}(\{a,c\})=\{1,2\},\ 
f^{-1}(\{b,c\})=\{3\},\\
f^{-1}(\{a,b,c\})=\{1,2,3\}.$$